# Problem with "Click Sound" on button click in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

i am working in the project in which i face the problem of playing the clicking sound on button click, i have done the following code on TouchDown Event of Buttons on every page

```
-(IBAction)ClickButtonSound:(id)sender
 {
     SystemSoundID theSound;
     NSString *pathToSound;
     pathToSound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"buttonsound" ofType:@"wav"] isDirectory:NO];
     OSStatus error = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)pathToSound,&theSound);
     NSLog(@"error=%@",error);
      AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (theSound);
     //[pathToSound release];

 }
```

this code is working well on simulator but when i test it on iphone device it gives humming sound,but not plays clicking sound so can anyone plese point out the reason why it is so?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you stop the sound from playing when you get the TouchUpEvent?

Comment: yes i did that.as i said it works fine on simulator but i don't know what's the problem with iPhone!!

Comment: Where is your soundfile located? 
Did you just drag it into your project or did you check the box where it copies your items into the destination group's folder.

(I had this same problem with some image file at some point, it was located on my pc and it worked fine on the simulator but it didn't see the file on the real device because that one wont have access to your source file then.)

Comment: ya,i appreciate your way of going in depth of problem but that is not the case here.it's there and copied to XCode project.thanks for your support. and if you have any other  way to play sound on click the button please let me know..

Comment: Hmm after some searching I haven't come up with a better way of coding  sound the way you want.
What I did find is another question to you:
Did you destroy the sound object anywhere?

Comment: yes i did that also in the - (void)dealloc
{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(theSound);

Comment: but now i get the another way which is not proper but works fine on the iphone also. using AVFoundation framework.so once again thanks for your support

Comment: No problem I'm sorry I couldn't be of service here. I don't see what's the problem here. I've seen these snippets that you're using everywhere.